# Computing $\int_{0}^1 \frac{\left( (1-x )a +x b\right)^2}{(1-x)c +x d} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to find the integral of 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^1   \frac{\left( (1-x )a +x b\right)^2}{(1-x)c +x d}dx
\end{align*}
for any $a,b$ and $c>0$ and $d>0$.

Using Wolfram-Alpha I found that the anti-derivative is given by
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^1   \frac{\left( (1-x)a +x b\right)^2}{(1-x)c +x d}d x &=-\frac{x(a-b)(acx-2ac-adx+4ad-bcx-2bc+bdx)}{2(c-d)^2} -\frac{(bc-ad)^2 \ln \left(c(x-1)-d x \right) }{2(c-d)^3}
\end{align*}

Now, observe that the second term has $\ln(c(x-1)-dx)$ so when I evaluated at $x=1$  we get $\ln(-d)$ which is complex number. How can this be, the argument of integral is well behaved function of $x$ on $(0,1)$?

I have tried several example but I never get a complex answer. For example

$a=5$ $b=6$, $c=10$ $d=7$ I get that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^1   \frac{\left( (1-x)a +x b\right)^2}{(1-x)c +x d}d x \approx 3.64
\end{align*}

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a tip why solve the form you have and not try to start by collecting terms?
$$
\frac{((1-x)a+xb)^2}{(1-x)c + xd} = \frac{((b-a)x+a)^2}{(d-c)x+c}
$$
then probably go with
$$
t = (d-c)x+c
$$
and go from there?

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{((1-x)a+xb)^2}{(1-x)c + xd} dx = \frac{1}{d-c}\int_c^d \frac{((b-a)\left(\frac{t-c}{d-c}\right)+a)^2}{t}dt 
$$

lets re-arrange
$$
\begin{align}
((b-a)\left(\frac{t-c}{d-c}\right)+a)^2 &=& \left(\frac{b-a}{d-c}\right)^2\left[t -c+a\frac{d-c}{b-a}\right]^2 \\
&=&\left(\frac{b-a}{d-c}\right)^2\left[t^2 + 2\left(a\frac{d-c}{b-a}-c\right)t + \left(a\frac{d-c}{b-a}-c\right)^2\right]
\end{align}
$$

so the integral becomes
$$
\frac{1}{d-c}\left(\frac{b-a}{d-c}\right)^2\int_c^d \frac{t^2 + 2\left(a\frac{d-c}{b-a}-c\right)t + \left(a\frac{d-c}{b-a}-c\right)^2}{t}dt\\
\frac{1}{d-c}\left(\frac{b-a}{d-c}\right)^2\int_c^d t + 2\left(a\frac{d-c}{b-a}-c\right) + \left(a\frac{d-c}{b-a}-c\right)^2\frac{1}{t}dt\\
\frac{1}{d-c}\left(\frac{b-a}{d-c}\right)^2\left[\frac{t^2}{2} + 2\left(a\frac{d-c}{b-a}-c\right)t + \left(a\frac{d-c}{b-a}-c\right)^2\ln (t)\right]_c^d
$$
putting in the limits we get
$$
\frac{1}{d-c}\left(\frac{b-a}{d-c}\right)^2\frac{d^2-c^2}{2} + 2\frac{1}{d-c}\left(\frac{b-a}{d-c}\right)^2\frac{ad-cb}{b-a}(d-c) + \frac{1}{d-c}\left(\frac{b-a}{d-c}\right)^2\frac{1}{(b-a)^2}\left(ad-cb\right)^2\ln \left(\frac{d}{c}\right)=\\
\left(\frac{b-a}{d-c}\right)^2\frac{d+c}{2} + 2\frac{(b-a)(ad-cb)}{(d-c)^2} + \frac{\left(ad-cb\right)^2}{(d-c)^3}\ln \left(\frac{d}{c}\right)=\\
\frac{(b-a)}{2(d-c)^2}\left(bd-ac+3(ad-cb)\right) + \frac{\left(ad-cb\right)^2}{(d-c)^3}\ln \left(\frac{d}{c}\right)
$$
so finally we reach this
$$
-\frac{(a-b)}{2(c-d)^2}\left(bd-ac+3(ad-cb)\right) - \frac{\left(bc-ad\right)^2}{(c-d)^3}\ln \left(\frac{d}{c}\right)
$$
The minus come from odd powers of terms i.e. $(b-a)^n = -(a-b)^n$ for $n$ is odd.

when comparing with wolfram we can utilise the fact that the first term only occurs for $x=1$ and in this case

$$
-\frac{(a-b)\left[ac-2ac-ad+4ad-bc-2bc+bd\right]}{2(c-d)^2} = -\frac{(a-b)\left(-ac+3ad-3bc+bd\right)}{2(c-d)^2}
$$
so checks with my other calculation. The log component I will leave as an exercise.

Comment: ok. Thanks. I will try

Comment: great stuff. I will update with a full answer after you worked through yourself :) and learning more in that process.

Comment: So, using what you suggested I got the integral is equal to $\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{b-a}{a-c} \left( d(  \frac{b-a}{a-c}d-4( c\frac{b-a}{a-c}-a)) -c(  \frac{b-a}{a-c}c-4( c\frac{b-a}{a-c}+a)  ) \right) + ( c\frac{b-a}{a-c}+a)^2 \log(d/c)\right)$. Is it correct? Also, I wonder if this can be simplified

Comment: I would take the equation you have given above and plug in the limits $0$ and $1$ and see if you get the same result (I have not worked the whole equation through yet). Do you mean simplify to Wolframs answer?

Comment: The equation I wrote is already with the limits. By simplify I mean mine. Do you mind working out your approach and then we compare. Thanks.

Comment: I meant the original solution from Wolfram (put the limits in that one). I can  write up the full solution but it will be on the other side of the commute.

Comment: Looking forward to your answer. If I put the limits in the solution from Wolfram  then I get $\log()$ with a minus inside.

Comment: You should get a $\log(t)$ which for the limits $t(x=0) = c,t(x=1) = d$ so no minus. But I will check.